# Cannot mount an image in Sierra that was created in High Sierra

Tags: macos, macos-sierra

I created an image in High Sierra and put on my external drive to mount on Sierra. But when I try to mount it, I get an error "No mountable file systems". What is this problem?

Comment: Did you use Disk Utility or hdiutil to check the details of your .dmg? Maybe High Sierra used its new APFS filesystem for the disk image rather than using something like HFS+ that Sierra would understand.

Comment: I used Disk Utility to create dmg.

Comment: I was trying to ask if you knew what kind of .dmg you created or what kind of filesystem it has on it. You can discover these things using Disk Utility or hdiutil. Disk Utility can create a wide variety of disk images with a wide variety of filesystems on them, so "I used Disk Utility to create it" doesn't mean a lot. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you probably set the image file system as APFS so it can be only read by High Sierra now.

I don't have High Sierra myself, but I've already found a couple of dmg on internet that I can't open and they are new. So, I guess they were created on High Sierra too.

Return to High Sierra and check the file system of the image. And try to change it. Provably you'll need to create a new image.

In El Capitan, [when you create a dmg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykcxL.png) the default file system is Mac OS Extended Journaled.